# how to call discount field from opportunity on totalprice field on related opportunitylineitem

Tags: apex, trigger

```
set<id> opps = new set<id>();
list<opportunity> lst = new list<opportunity>([select id,discount [select id,totalprice from opportunitylineitem  ] from opportunity where Id IN : opps]);
for (opportunity olt : lst){
    for (opportunitylineitem oppo : olt.opportunitylineitems)
    {
        Oppo.totalprice =   Oppo.totalprice -   Oppo.totalprice*olt.discount
    }
```

Comment: Is discount custom field?

Comment: @rahulgawale yes it is in opportunity object

Comment: This code will not compile. SOQL is invalid.

Comment: how can i overcome that error

Comment: @Reshma how can use map for the same code can you help please

Comment: @raja Why do you want to use map and how?

Comment: to optimize code and learn how map is used@Reshma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will compile. You can get `discount__c` field value from opportunity and calculate `totalprice` on corresponding Opportunitylineitems.

```
Set<id> opps = new Set<id>();//Not sure how this set get populated
for(Opportunity olt : [SELECT Id,discount__c,(SELECT id,totalprice FROM Opportunitylineitems) FROM opportunity WHERE Id IN :opps]){
    for (Opportunitylineitem oppo : olt.Opportunitylineitems){
        oppo.totalprice = Oppo.totalprice - (Oppo.totalprice*olt.discount__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy discount from opportunity to Discount field on Line item

```
set<id> opps = new set<id>();
    //.. add opp ids to list
    list<opportunity> lst = [select id,Discount__c, (select id,totalprice from OpportunityLineItems) from opportunity where Id IN : opps];
    for(opportunity opp : lst){
        for (opportunitylineitem lineitem : opp.OpportunityLineItems){
            lineitem.Discount = opp.Discount__c;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code won't compile as it has syntax errors... also The new List constructor is an over kill

Comment: @PranayJaiswal updated my answer. Sorry for that blunder.

Comment: how can we use map for the same code @rahulgawale